# Hive: Quotes in user defined variable

Tags: sql, azure, hive

I am trying to use the user defined variable in Hive (in Azure) in the following query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydb.mytable(
  Time STRING,
  Src STRING,
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/${hiveconf:OLD_DATE_FORMAT}/'
```

It works when I set

```
set OLD_DATE_FORMAT = 2015/07/11
```

But, it does not work when I set

```
set set OLD_DATE_FORMAT = regexp_replace(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'), 2), '-', '/');
```

It throws an error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 14:147 missing EOF at 'yyyy' near ''wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/regexp_replace(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),''
```

My guess is, the single quotes in the user defined variable are causing the problem.

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: `unix_timestamp` returns a BIGINT. so when you convert the date it will be a number, not a date. Hence your regexp throws an error.

Comment: well, from_unixtime converts it to the string. So, I think this is not a problem.

Comment: Why the regexp_replace? Couldn't you just use the format you need in from_unixtime() ?

Comment: from_unixtime didnt work if the format is "yyyy/mm/dd". from_unixtime worked for format "yyyy-mm-dd".